# Is this IDisposable returned from a function being disposed of properly?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I have a class that performs data access using a `SqlConnection`, which as we all know implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) and should be disposed of in a finally block or via a using statement. I have them in using blocks, but my `IDisposable` is actually created in a separate function. Like this:

```
public class DataRepository
{
    private readonly SqlConfiguration _configuration;

    public DataRepository(SqlConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void Save(Model someModel)
    {
        using(var connection = CreateSqlConnection())
        {
            // Use connection here
        }
    }

    public Model Get(int id)
    {
        using(var connection = CreateSqlConnection())
        {
            // Use connection here
        }
    }

    private SqlConnection CreateSqlConnection()
        => new SqlConnection(_configuration.ConnectionString);
}
```

As you can see, I've got using statements handling all my `SqlConnection`'s. There is no place that `CreateSqlConnection` is called outside of a using statement. However, I  am using Code Cracker Roslyn Analyzers and it's giving me a [CC0022](https://code-cracker.github.io/diagnostics/CC0022.html) warning in my `CreateSqlConnection` that:

> SqlConnection should be disposed.

Have I properly ensured that my `SqlConnection` is getting disposed of? Is the code analyzer just incorrect in this case?

Comment: Yes, if its in a `using` block then it will be disposed.

Comment: Try simply renaming `CreateSqlConnection` to `GetSqlConnection` and see if that works. I think the particular rule is finicky about the name of your method as well.

Comment: looks good to me. I assume it's the roslyn analyzer seeing the "potential" for it to not be disposed of because it's in a method anything could call and isn't disposed of within "CreateSqlConnection". Looks safe to me though with what you've done.

Comment: Looks fine to me; I wonder what happens if you replace `CreateSqlConnection` with the traditional style of method declaration (`return new ...` rather than the `=>`) - maybe the analyzer can cope in that case.

Comment: A little bit offtopic, but I do not find it a good idea to create connections inside the repository.  The connection should be passed to the repository, since the repository doesn't know the context of usage of the connection.
It might be perfectly possible that you want to execute multiple methods on the same connection or even inside one transaction.  That is not possible in the way you're doing it now

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, changing it to `GetSqlConnection` made no difference.

Comment: @SamHolloway Yes, changing it to a traditional method eliminated the warning. I guess the analyzer would just need to be adjusted to handle expression bodied function members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a deliberate decision by the folks working on Code Cracker. In general the entire lifetime of the object can't be known, so they raise the CC0022 diagnostic. See [this discussion](https://github.com/code-cracker/code-cracker/issues/432) on their bug tracker.

Clearly in this case you **can** know the lifetime of all invocations of that object, but it may be implementing that in the code analyzer was considered just one step too much...