# Will using block close database connection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ado.net

Will using block close a database connection, even if the connection object is created in another class?

I see multiple article says, below code will close connection automatically, and no need to call the `close()` method, and I agree with this.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConn))
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    // do database stuff
    //conn.Close(); //// Not required.
}
```

But in my application, we follow this coding style:

```
public class DBConnectionBackboneService : IDBConnectionBackboneService
{
    public OracleConnection GetDBConnection()
    {
        string conString = "<<Connection-String>>;
        return new OracleConnection(conString);
    }
}

class main()
{
    using (dbConnection = _dbConnectionRepo.GetDBConnection())
    {
        dbConnection.Open();

        // Call database procedure.

        // Work with dataset.
    }
}
```

I understand connection reference is same in main class, so ideally it should close connection, but just wanted to confirm if my understanding is correct, or I should close connection manually?

Comment: Yes, it will be closed and disposed

Comment: Also while you are at it, do you ever use a connection if it is closed? No, then I would add the Open call directly into the GetDBConnection or I would add another method called GetOpenDBConnection

Comment: I asked a [very similar but not quite the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723322/is-this-idisposable-returned-from-a-function-being-disposed-of-properly) 7 years ago.

Comment: Yes, and I understood, it will close the connection. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be closed since that's what the `Dispose` method does in `SqlConnection`.

Please note that a method that returns an instance of any class that implements the `IDisposable` interface should return a new instance any time it's called, to prevent a possible `ObjectDisposedException` to be thrown when a reference to the same instance is being handled in two different methods (possibly running in parallel).